# Odd results from ie/edge when getting bounding rect of selected text close to document border

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom, microsoft-edge

Basic fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p6790wv9/

When trying to get the bounding rectangle of selected text everything works as expected in Firefox or Chrome but with the same code on IE and Chrome I'm experiencing odd results when selecting the last word* in a row.

For example this is the bounding rectangle when selecting the last word in the first row in Firefox:

```
{
    x: 552.4166870117188,
    y: 28.5,
    width: 40.866668701171875,
    height: 19, 
    top: 28.5,
    right: 593.2833557128906,
    bottom: 47.5,
    left: 552.4166870117188 
}
```

This is the result from IE 11:

```
{
    bottom: 63.199996948, 
    constructor: ClientRect {...},
    height: 36.799995422, 
    left: 8, // This is wrong!
    right: 597.23999023, 
    top: 26.399999618, 
    width: 589.23999023 // ??
}
```

This is the js code used to obtain the previous two:

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
if (selection && selection.toString() !== "") {
   rect = selection.getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();
   console.log(rect);
}
```

I'm making sure the selection doesn't include any words from the following row (I just double click the word to select it).

Is this behaviour known/expected? Am I missing something?

EDIT: 
*When I wrote last word of a row, I meant the text closer to the right border of the document, sorry it's late o\

Comment: More code is probably needed to help you out on this. Please take a moment to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins
The jsfiddle link has the relevant code, but I'll add more here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the first issue is the browser clearly have different default styles and you don't have any CSS specified on the text you are creating your ranges on.

If you specify font-size and line-height and set a wild card pardding and margin to 0 the numbers start get closer.

However some things are being interpreted different.

For example 8pt font with 12pt line-height gives me 15 or 16px rect height (as expected) in IE Edge. But FireFox puts the rectangle height to 12 to 13px height. I am not sure why it varies by one pixel but it is apparent IE's height is based on line height but Firefox's height is based on font' size.

The point is each browser is making uses its own calculations.

```js
document.getElementById("lorem").addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);

function mouseup() {
  selection = window.getSelection();
  if (selection && selection.toString() !== "") {
   rect = selection.getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(rect);
  }
}
```

```css
* {margin:0px;padding:0px;}
#lorem {
  font-size:8pt;
  line-height:12pt;
  font-family:arial;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="lorem">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pretium mauris eu turpis rhoncus, et dictum nunc eleifend. Nullam ultricies iaculis lorem, eget faucibus purus ornare et. Aenean et tortor elementum, commodo urna sed, sollicitudin augue. Integer
        pharetra iaculis augue, vitae vulputate magna pulvinar ac. Curabitur pretium augue eu mi gravida ultricies. Ut semper luctus nisl a pretium. Aliquam at lacus vel justo porttitor rhoncus sit amet quis mi. Integer ac enim condimentum, malesuada
        massa ut, fermentum lacus. Nullam laoreet elit eu diam lacinia euismod. Nullam nec aliquet mauris, et maximus erat. Proin in ex justo. Aliquam dictum nisl vitae molestie tempor. Quisque id turpis at metus dictum ultrices in ac augue. Fusce tempus
        tincidunt sem at commodo. Donec dapibus erat sed finibus consequat. Nullam et nisi lacus. Sed diam quam, faucibus vulputate egestas a, consequat a enim. Donec congue velit molestie, vulputate ante quis, finibus odio. Integer et erat sed ligula
        egestas ornare sit amet quis nunc. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi feugiat libero nec lacus elementum malesuada. Fusce dictum turpis velit, in suscipit nibh tincidunt ut. Sed viverra tellus risus, vel laoreet augue lobortis nec. Suspendisse
        tincidunt semper ante. Vestibulum sodales risus posuere enim placerat, ut convallis tortor mollis. Curabitur vitae dictum tortor. Curabitur pellentesque, enim eu malesuada placerat, nibh nulla iaculis mi, et vestibulum lorem metus vitae eros.
        Ut nec ipsum in libero volutpat placerat. Suspendisse feugiat quam eu mauris elementum, sit amet venenatis velit malesuada. In iaculis eu odio id elementum. Curabitur nec augue ut turpis volutpat auctor ac non nunc. Sed posuere, purus quis accumsan
        aliquam, mi sapien ultricies augue, sed bibendum nisl nibh id nulla. Aliquam fermentum elit ac condimentum laoreet. Sed pharetra elit gravida metus vulputate, a pharetra magna finibus. Aenean tincidunt orci sed libero sollicitudin cursus. Donec
        sapien nisl, molestie non elementum et, efficitur ut lectus. Nulla scelerisque non arcu et sodales. Aliquam nisi neque, fermentum non arcu in, efficitur fermentum lorem. Proin laoreet magna lorem, a molestie leo sollicitudin efficitur. In hendrerit
        purus et nulla lobortis, eget efficitur nisl aliquet. Donec nisl erat, tempus hendrerit lorem iaculis, varius feugiat purus. Aenean ac dolor eget ipsum blandit iaculis vel sed justo. Mauris tortor tortor, interdum vitae lectus id, ultricies vulputate
        nibh. Cras convallis, risus eget semper scelerisque, erat urna tincidunt nisl, vel ultricies dui neque a felis. Pellentesque ut ligula vitae tortor tincidunt pellentesque in id nunc. Ut ac dictum quam. Nulla pretium commodo libero, quis tempor
        mi pulvinar ac. Aliquam sagittis ex arcu, a scelerisque urna commodo in. Curabitur pharetra posuere efficitur. Mauris blandit urna vel libero euismod faucibus. Pellentesque laoreet magna ex. Vivamus commodo orci et commodo egestas. Nulla vel dapibus
        libero.
</div>    
</body>
```

Comment: I see your point about line height and different browser calculations, but I still don't get the .left data.
Why IE it's still returning a number like the selected text would be positioned on the left of the document?

Comment: Your height: 36.799995422 shows me you are selecting multiple lines.

Comment: Yeah now I see ie / edge are treating it as if multiple lines are selected as shown in this gif: https://gfycat.com/SimilarBelatedBarnswallow

Still it's an annoying and unexpected, especially since it's not visible and the other browsers are not doing it.

I guess one more ie/edge fix to implent ;) ?

Comment: Yep, that's another oddity between the browsers. They vary in selecting extra white space before and after you selection unless you are super specific with your mouse.